# AWS IAM Pass Role Action Audit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Anyone knows how I can track if IAM pass role action (inside a role) is being used by any services or not? As per AWS document the "iam:PassRole" action is not tracked under IAM access advisor: [Refining Permissions Using Service Last Accessed Data - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor.html#access_policies_access-advisor-know)

I have this policy inside a IAM role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I suspect that data is present in CloudTrail.

Comment: I tried that but don't see any event name "PassRole"

Comment: I don't think this is trackable. An API call will 'use' PassRole, but there isn't an API call for PassRole itself.

Comment: yes, I think so, below query in Athena to query CloudTrail returns nothing.
```
SELECT *
FROM cloudtrail_logs
WHERE eventname='PassRole';
```